# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - How to emulate the Busy Indicator in iOS native page

Tags: ios, spinner, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there any objective C API which can call the busy indicator in native page which the UI is same as that using "WL.BusyIndicator" in html page? The reason is that I would like to keep the style consistent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight does not provide any UI-related API in the native SDK (for either iOS or Android). This is available only through the Worklight framework for Hybrid apps.

In fact, even in iOS there is no busy indicator provided by the OS; well, that's not true, it [comes in a different form](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIActivityIndicatorView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIActivityIndicatorView) ([more info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)) and there is some pesudo-standard for it amongst native apps.

What is done in a Worklight Hybrid app is simply take what the OS provides and customize it via a Cordova plug-in. This plug-in is not publicly available.

So you will need to create your own spinner code and make its appearance the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I further know if it is possible to share the spinner code which Worklight is currently using for iOS? For Android, I know that it is using Android native ProgressDialog so I can make the appearance the same. However, I am not sure the approach used in Worklight to create the overlay and style of the spinner for iOS. It is not easily to make it exactly the same. Thanks.